# About administrators who can use admin-sdk

Tags: privileges, google-admin-sdk, administrator

https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/quickstart/python

Is the "Google account for that domain with administrator privileges" mentioned in this prerequisite a super administrator?

https://support.google.com/a/answer/2405986

Or are other admins included?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Others included, depends on the level of access you want to have. For example, you can have a Custom Admin role with Users and Groups Read permission, that will allow you to read all information about users and groups (but you will not be able to modify/add users).